# Android UiAutomator Testing

Tags: android, exception, android-uiautomator

I have created a simple activity in which I have 2 buttons for submitting and cancel. I just want to test this project by using UI Automator testing. So I create an android test project and make a class. I make this test class extend `UiAutomatorTestCase`. I have also added uiautomator.jar, android.jar as well as the junit3 library. But when I run the test case, it gives me an error about

> TestSuiteConstruction failed and java.lang.RuntimeException.

However I add constructor but as it does not take any parameter, so I am unable to add any paramater. Here is my test case code. Please solve this error as soon as possible. Can you please tell me anything that I have not added in my project?

```
package com.example.automatorapp.test;

import android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;
import com.example.automatorapp.MainActivity;

public class testDemo1 extends UiAutomatorTestCase
{
    public testDemo1()
    {

    }

    public void testdemo() throws UiObjectNotFoundException
    {   
        getUiDevice().pressHome();
        Log.e("how r u","hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: pleasse replyy someone??its urgent!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAutomator junit testsuite error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674279/uiautomator-junit-testsuite-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the name of your class so that is does **not** start with 'test' and remove the constructor. By convention, the name of a class starts with a Capital letter, yours starts with the lowercase 't'. Also, again by convention, JUnit3 test classes put the word 'Test' at the end. http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/TestCase.html So in your example a class name of testdemo1 would be something line Demo1Test (remember the filename needs to match the classname).

However, and to my surprise, a slightly modified version of your code ran on my machine. Here's the code that ran OK.

```
package com.example.automatorapp.test;

import android.util.Log;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class testDemo1 extends UiAutomatorTestCase
{
    public testDemo1()
    {
    }
    public void testdemo() throws UiObjectNotFoundException
    {
        getUiDevice().pressHome();
        Log.e("how r u","hello");
    }
}
```

I got the Log message in the Android log too.

`E/how r u (24667): hello`

Therefore, you may have some issues with your project setup or build environment. As far as I know this project (for testing) should be independent of the code or project for the app you want to test. However you have an import to the app you want to test.

`import com.example.automatorapp.MainActivity;`

As you've now posted quite a few questions related to UI Automator perhaps you could summarise your progress so far. For example, have you ever got a UI Automator test to run successfully?

PS: I hoped to see some feedback to answers to your earlier questions. Without your feedback it's hard to know which way you're heading and whether the answers were relevant or useful to you.

Comment: heyy thanks for your valuable comment..actually can you please tell me do i have to use terminal also for running this test or can i directly run by writing code in ide.As in some test cases i have seen that there is build.xml file.How can i create that?And 1 more question do i have to attach javadoc also for uiautomator.jar?

Comment: heyy i think i am missing some jar files..can u please tell me step by step how can i make my TestCase in UiAutomator..meanss i have made steps like..                                                 new->AndroidTestPorject.After that i go to properties and import uiautomator.jar as well as androi.jar.And i also add JUNit3 library.  Thats all i done from myside.Do i have to do something more??and 1 thing i am unablt to find javadoc of uiautomator.jar.plzz help me as soon as possible?

Comment: Puneet, Rather than using new->AndroidTestProject I recommend you follow the example on the Android developer site here http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#creating read it carefully e.g. the tests go in the /src folder. Then keep reading and experimenting and copy their sample test http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html#sample then **on the command line** repeat the various commands shown in the example. You can work with the code in an IDE but most of the work is on a command-line. Maybe ask a colleague who knows Android for help too? Good luck.

Comment: heyy julian thanks for your help..but actually is it mandatory to use command line for uiautomator testing?And for creating testcase,do i have to put both class which has to be test and testcase in same source?

Comment: Nothing is **mandatory** because a good techie can find ways to implement alternative approachs e.g. it's *possible* to write some software to integrate UI Automator into an IDE. However, for now, the practical answer for you would be to use the command line tools, and learn how to use them competently. You may then be able to devise better approaches that suit your needs better. UI Automator, unlike Android Instrumentation, lives separately from the code you want to test. Treat your UI Automator project as an independent, separate project; that's how the Android example works.

Comment: heyy i tried all the steps that mention in developers.android.com site..but still there are errors..i think that when i build testcase there is some problem,something is missing from me that i have to add..can u pleas tell me in brief some steps of how to make testcase?and what i have to do from command line?? thanks in advance for ur answer..

Comment: Puneet, I don't think it's practical or productive for me to write  steps for how to make a testcase & get it working on your machine as part of answering questions on Stack Overflow. The Android documentation covers the main steps and includes the commands you need to use from the command line. I've answered your various main questions and tested each time & often provided the output from the command line commands, etc. **Note** the Android example is standalone, no test project, no target app. Perhaps you can get someone locally to work alongside you and help you diagnose what's going wrong?

Comment: yess you are right..okie i will try from my side..thankss for your help!!

Comment: All the best in your exploration and discovery. I hope you are able to resolve the issues in your setup & then move on to using UI Automator successfully. Please let me know when you're ready to test the various answers and get more involved with using UI Automator.

Comment: heyy i am very thankful to you for your help..i have run successfully uiautomator case..now actually i have to use adaptxt application for testing..in this i have to enter 1 word and from the suggestion box i have to pick first word.Do you have any idea how can we handle suggestion box meanss how can we choose word from the suggestion box?

Comment: Puneet, I'm pleased you managed to successfully run a UI Automator test case. Can I ask you to do several things now: a) review all your questions on StackOverflow & tidy them up. For instance, close those that are similar. In future, I suggest you limit each question to one question, rather than adding extra questions to them e.g. I've seen you report similar problems 3 or 4 times e.g. for exceptions & for 'missing javadocs'. b) accept any and all of my answers if they answered that question. c) write a new question, with a clear example of what you now want to achieve, and any relevant code.

Comment: heyy surely i will do that all what you say..actually i am testing adaptxt keyboard in android.Can u please tell me how can i make a long press on any key of adaptxt in emulator?